# Obtener valores dinámicos de arrays dinámicos en un modelo

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero obtener los datos de un modelo **Audit**, que dentro de sus columnas **old_values** y **new_values** se almacenan arrays, pero dinámicos. Cuando hago el `foreach` en la vista me da el siguiente error al querer mostrar dichas columnas:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: H:\DAF\resources\views\audit\index.blade.php)

Ya e buscado en varios blog y dicen como hacer algo parecido pero con arrays estáticos, no con dinámicos.

El modelo **Audit** es el vendor de `Laravel` para auditar llamado `OwenIt\Auditing`.

```
class Audit extends Model implements \OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Audit
{
    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Audit;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'old_values'   => 'json',
        'new_values'   => 'json',
        'auditable_id' => 'integer',
    ];
}
```

**Controlador**

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use OwenIt\Auditing\Models\Audit;

    class EstaticasController extends Controller {
        public function audit() {
            $audit = Audit::orderBy( 'id', 'DESC' )->get();
            return view( 'audit.index', compact( 'audit' ) );
        }
    }
```

**Vista**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-stripped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Operaci&oacute;n</th>
                        <th>Tupla</th>
                        <th>Tabla</th>
                        <th>Valores antiguos</th>
                        <th>Valores Actuales</th>
                        <th>URL</th>
                        <th>IP</th>
                        <th>Creado</th>
                        <th>Actualizado</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php $no = 1 ?>
                    @foreach($audit as $item)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->event }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->auditable_id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->auditable_type }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->old_values }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->new_values }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->url }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->ip_address }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->created_at }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->updated_at }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

**Datos en la BD**
[image]

Comment: ¿Podemos ver el código del foreach y el controlador?

Comment: public function audit() {
   $audit = Audit::orderBy( 'id', 'DESC' )->get();
   return view( 'audit.index', compact( 'audit' ) );
  }

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega dicho código ahí, no en los comentarios.

Comment: ¿Cómo deseas mostrar dicho campo?

Comment: de esta forma {"name":"valor",....}